# How to produce series of image in div from input from textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to find out good solution to the issue I have at the moment, I am tryign to improve my understanding of javascript atm.

My problem is trying to produce series of images that is directly produce from what the users have input into the textbox.

For example If I put in "Hello" into textbox, I want to produce 5 images in row into div of display particular way of how to fingerspell "Hello" but need to know how to seperate each character and produce image that is direct relate to each character individual.

Then it would be produce into div contain 5 seperate images placed together and shown.

Help would be appreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply wire up a [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) and then you can use [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate through each character in the string and than call [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add in your `<img/>` `<div/>` or other elements.

```
$("#spell").change(function(){
    var $o = $("#output").empty();
    $.each($(this).val(), function(i, c){
        $o.append("<img src='http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff&text=" + c + "'/>");
    });
});
```

**[Code example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/QUPu8/)**

If you want this to occur while they type you could use `.keyup()`

Comment: You know how to replace the dummyimage placeholder for another image, I dont want image version of text, I want 'A' character to be stand in for A in British Sign Language image?

Comment: All you would need to do is replace `src='http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff&text=" + c + "'` with `src='Someurltotheimage'`, e.g. if your image is `a.jpg` for British Sign Language `a` you would just need to do `src='/yourfolder/images/" + c +".jpg'`

Comment: can it work with '/Images/" + c +".png' cause it is not producing the result at all, the images I have are in the files but have no luck so far, I wonder how do I figure what is preventing the results

Comment: www.chriskeeley.net/MP/ - from there you can click on learning button then go to bottom - and explain the reason for what I have done wrong so I can learn from this mistake - thank

Comment: @Chris, try this, http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/QUPu8/2/ , needed to call `.toUpperCase()` on each `c` so it can pull in your images correctly.

Comment: Thank for your help mark, fantastic support you have provide for me, same for Neal, any advice on what books or how to improve my understanding of javascript so I would have ability to craft my own codes, just need to improve myself as designer/programmer

Comment: I wish I could try answer questions on SO - shame I only have good understanding of HTML and CSS but who doesnt =)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/9UdLy/

And here is the code:

```
$("#img").keyup(function() {

    var chars = this.value.split("");
    var rez = $("#rez").html('');

    $.each(chars, function(index, item) {
        var img = $('<img>', {
            src: 'http://www.placehold.it/100x100/eee/&text=' + item 
        });
        rez.append(img);
    })

})
```